# Need Guidance - NPM publishing the library ( Using JavaScript and Storybook)

Tags: javascript, npm, gitlab, npm-publish

I am little new in publishing our own , newly created lib. Please help me with my basic questions.

I have created my own library using plain JavaScript and Storybook. Not sure how to publish it and How to use it in any project say, new project created using react Create app.

**Want to know**

- Do we need to create npm account to publish the library?
- I have gitlab account, will that do ?
- What’s the difference between publishing the library in npmjs or
  gitlab/ github packages?

Can someone please provide me detail steps to build the library and then use it?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have added issue at gitlab as well https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/358698